# Big video to string base64 causes outofmemoryerror

Tags: android, string, web-services, arrays

i need to send video to webservice in .net, im send a string base64 encode, if the video its about 2MB or 6 o 7 seconds all its ok, but when is more heavy causes outofmemoryerror when i do Bas.encode[byte[]);

This is my code:

```
videoPath = getRealPathFromURI(fileUri);
                            File tmpFile = new File(videoPath);
                            in = null;
                            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(tmpFile));
                            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            long tamano = tmpFile.length();
                            int iTamano = (int) tamano;
                            byte[] b = new byte[iTamano];
                            int bytesRead;
                            while ((bytesRead = in.read(b)) != -1) {
                                bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
                            }
                            ficheroAEnviar = bos.toByteArray();
try {
                    strBase64 = Base64.encode(ficheroAEnviar);

                }
                catch (Exception e) {

                    correcto = false;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Crash in this line:                         strBase64 = Base64.encode(ficheroAEnviar);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do like this. The memory is an issue in android. You should split the video in few parts, encode each part, send it (I think you want to send it over a WS or something) and recombine it on destination.

Comment: why not? You read in packages: x kb per package, mark the last byte read (position) and start reading on the same position on the next package. Each package is encoded as base64 and sent. The only issue is to combine the parts on the server side to obtain the video.

Comment: Just to be sure you understand my solution: don't read whole video in one step, read only subparts of it, encode the part, send it and do the same for the next part.

Comment: +1 for the solution: **You should split the video in few parts, encode each part, send it (I think you want to send it over a WS or something) and recombine it on destination.**